# Как правильно взаимодействовать в разметке со значениями BehaviorSubject из сервиса?

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4, angular5

Как я понял - правильно создавать не просто переменные, а BehaviorSubject ли Subject в сервисе и потом на них ссылаться в разметке, хотя при изменении значений у меня и без этого они сразу же отрисовывались в разметке. Но вопрос в другом. Я вывожу из сервиса значение типа myserviceName.mydata.getValue()
а вносить так не получается если я поставлю в input [model]. я так и не понял, как правильно вытащить данные и внести. Через set можно внести, но я вообще фишку этих потоков не очень понял, когда всё работает и так, если я переменные создаю и с разных мест их меняю(хотя это не лучший вариант как я понял)

Comment: В документации ангуляра очень много примеров. Отдельно можно посмотреть примеры по `async` пайпе. Ну а потом, нет такого понятия, потоковое значение поля правильно, обычное неправильно. Все зависит от цели и конкретного случая применения

Comment: @Yugofx если взять простой пример - в одном компоненте через input вводится значение - оно сохраняется в сервис и в другом компоненте видишь значение из сервиса. Как именно такое сдалать?